# How do I extract a paragraph following a defined text in Python?

Tags: python, extract, sentence

I have a text file in the following format in which certain paragraphs are marked with a set of asterisks, like this:

```
This 'impossibility' is the inspiration of his work.

********
There are no methods that comprehend his subject.
```

Using Python, how can I extract only those paragraphs following the set of asterisks?

Comment: Well, can you explain step by step how you would solve the problem, if you were only allowed to look at the file a line at a time (but are allowed to remember things that you did before)? Can you come up with a rule that says whether a line should be extracted or not? Now that you know how to handle each line, do you know how to write code that does the same thing `for` each line `in` the file (hint, hint)?

Comment: Please read [ask]. I understand that you are frustrated, but Stack Overflow still expects you to make some attempt to write code first. If you generally have the problem that you don't know where to begin with writing a new piece of code, *then Stack Overflow is not the right place to get help*. Try to follow tutorials until you are confident enough in what you can do with the language; or try using an actual discussion forum such as Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
string = "******** There are no methods that comprehend his subject."
paragraph = string[string.find("********")+8:]
```

where string.find finds the index of that specific string in the paragraph and you add 8 to it because that is how many asterisks there are.